# Observe row data of a column in a dataframe and see if the value changes one by one

Tags: python, dataframe

I got a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10,10,10,14,14,15], columns = ['A']) 

    A
0  10
1  10
2  10
3  14
4  14
5  15
```

I need to create a new column named 'valueChange'. When the value of column 'A' changes, the row of valueChange will be 'True'.

So it'd be turn out like this:

```
    A  valueChange
0  10   False
1  10   False 
2  10   False
3  14   True
4  14   False
5  15   True
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
l = df.A.tolist()
df["valueChange"] = [False]+[ l[a]!= l[(a-1)] for a in range(1,len(l))]
```